# ListView doesn't refresh

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a `Custom ListView` that contains some `Views`. when I click on one `ImageView` that's called 'deleteRow', the Selected Item should be removed from the `Database` and also from my `ListView`,

I have successfully removed that item from the database, but the `ListView` doesn't get refreshed, here is my `getView()` code:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView==null)
    {
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.espaceclientuploadsource, null);
        holder.nomduProduit = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.UploadedProductName);
        holder.prixDuProduit = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.UplodedProductPrice);
        holder.imageDuProduit = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Uplodimage);
        holder.status = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.UploadedStatus);
        holder.deleteRow=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewDeleteRow);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path+File.separator+lesProduits.get(position).getImage());

    Drawable drawableImage = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapImage);
    holder.imageDuProduit.setImageDrawable(drawableImage);
    holder.nomduProduit.setText(lesProduits.get(position).getNomDuProduit());
    holder.prixDuProduit.setText(lesProduits.get(position).getPrixDuProduit());
    holder.deleteRow.setImageResource(R.drawable.deleteRow);


    holder.deleteRow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
        Context ctx = v.getContext();
        produitSource=new ProductsDataSource(ctx);
        produitSource.open();
        produitSource.deleteUpload(lesProduits.get(position));          
        produitSource.close();

        }
    });


    switch (lesProduits.get(position).getStatus())
    {

    case 3://annonce Accepté
    holder.status.setImageResource(R.drawable.accepte); 
    break;

    case 2://annonce en Attente
    holder.status.setImageResource(R.drawable.enattente);   
    break;

    case 1://annonce refusé
    holder.status.setImageResource(R.drawable.refuse);
    break;

    case 0://produit vendu
    holder.status.setImageResource(R.drawable.vendu);
    break;
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: after the removal code call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter to refresh listview

Comment: post your adapter code please.

Comment: I would have called the delete from the MAIN Activity and would have refreshed the ListViewAdapter

Answer (score 1):

**`notifyDataSetChanged()`** is the function used on the ListAdapter to refresh your ListView.

Exceprt from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)  :

> **`public void notifyDataSetChanged ()`**
>
> Notifies the attached observers that the
>   underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set
>   should refresh itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ContentProvider` needs to notify that the data set has been changed anytime a database write operation runs, ie:

```
@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
    //Some delete code
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
}
```

You need to call notifyChange in the insert and update methods as well.

---

Also, since your data is clearly dependent upon the database. You should be making use of a `CursorAdapter` and not a general `ArrayAdapter`. Using the one included in the support package is best.

An example of a `CursorAdapter`:

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, c, autoRequery);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context con, Cursor c) {
        //set the data on your view
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context con, Cursor c, ViewGroup vg) {
        //just create your view, no need to set the data, it will be called again in bindview
    }
}
```

Now, whenever your database is updated, the `ListView` will autoupdate, and you gain some memory optimizations by using the CursorAdapter instead.

Comment: Where i need to override the delete method?
do i need to call it somewhere?

Comment: In your ContentProvider class

Answer (score 0):

You should refresh your listView adapter. Recreate your adapter and replace it with the old one. Hope this helps.

Comment: the problem was that i want it to be refreshed once an onClick method from a different class is called.